# Activated Ruby RAKE 10.0.1, require 10.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I get this error when i try to run "rake test":

```
avery@ubuntu:~/rails_projects/depot$ rake test
rake aborted!
You have already activated rake 10.0.1, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.0.0. Using bundle exec may solve this.
/home/avery/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `block in setup'
/home/avery/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:17:in `setup'
/home/avery/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
/home/avery/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/avery/rails_projects/depot/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/home/avery/rails_projects/depot/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/avery/rails_projects/depot/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

when i try running "bundle exec rake" i get:

```
rake aborted!
Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
/home/avery/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect'
/home/avery/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
/home/avery/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/avery/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `require'
/home/avery/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/avery/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `require'
/home/avery/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/avery/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `require'
/home/avery/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/avery/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/home/avery/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/avery/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/home/avery/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
/home/avery/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/home/avery/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/home/avery/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
/home/avery/rails_projects/depot/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/avery/rails_projects/depot/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/home/avery/rails_projects/depot/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 16):

You probably have `rake 10.0.0` in your `Gemfile.lock`.

Removing `Gemfile.lock` might solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

For the first part of the question: I ran into the same problem and solved it with a:

```
gem regenerate_binstubs
```

after that

```
gem -V
```

reveals 10.0.0 again.

Answer (score 3):

### Answer of 1st query

In your `Gemfile`, explicitly set the latest rake version by

```
gem 'rake', '~> 10.0.1'
```

And then run

```
$ bundle update rake
```

### Answer of 2nd query

put this in your `Gemfile` and run bundle install

```
gem 'therubyracer'
```

Answer (score 2):

For the second part of the question, you just need to add this to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'therubyracer'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've specified a rake version in your Gemfile that your project requires, eg:

```
gem 'rake', '~> 10.0.0'
```

Try installing it again

```
bundle install
```