# rake aborted! You have already activated rake 10.0.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I am trying to do "rake db:migrate" and it is giving me this error.

```
Andy:AcademyAir Andy$ rake db:migrate
/Users/Andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:197: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
rake aborted!
You have already activated rake 10.0.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.2.2. Using bundle exec may solve this.
/Users/Andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `block in setup'
/Users/Andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:17:in `setup'
/Users/Andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
/Users/Andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Andy/Desktop/AcademyAir/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Andy/Desktop/AcademyAir/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Andy/Desktop/AcademyAir/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Get a look at the [link][1]. It may solve the problem.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400587/activated-ruby-rake-10-0-1-require-10-0-0/13418530#13418530

Comment: possible duplicate of [You have already activated rake 0.9.0, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.8.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080040/you-have-already-activated-rake-0-9-0-but-your-gemfile-requires-rake-0-8-7)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try this `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

**Remove rake 10.0.2 gem**

By using `gem uninstall rake` and remove `10.0.2` version of rake gem

And Then Try `rake db:migrate`

**Why Error comes** : In you gem list two version (10.0.2 and 0.9.2.2) of rake gem install so that this error comes.*

Another Solution is you can do `bundle update`

Comment: ```bundle exec rake db:migrate
/Users/Andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:197: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
/Users/Andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:197: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777```

Comment: Now when i try to rake db:migarte it just do nothing.
```Andy:academyair Andy$ rake db:migrate
/Users/Andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:197: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
Andy:academyair Andy$ ```

Comment: check your table that may be migration run before or also possible that migration doesn't have table in your migration file in your db folder check it both

Comment: This worked, but I had to run bundle install afterwards, and then it was fixed.

The reason this was broken, in my case, was that I had two projects sharing the same gemset with rvm. The rake versions were different. Using different gemsets was the answer.

Comment: Thanks, after searching a lot finally this resolved my issue.

Answer (score 42):

For me, I just ran `bundle update` and everything works right again.

Comment: But this will also update other gems,so a work around for this would be to change the rake version in Gemfile.lock from 0.9.2.2 to 10.0.1 and then run bundle command.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to solve this by opening up Gemfile and changing `gem 'rake', '~> 0.9.2.2'` to `gem 'rake', '~> 10.0.1'`

Answer (score 4):

In your `Gemfile`, explicitly set the latest rake version by:

```
gem 'rake', '~> 10.0.1'
```

And then run

```
$ bundle update rake
```

Then try

Comment: ou should first delete your Gemfile.lock file and bundle install again and then use

rake db:migrate

Answer (score 3):

I've just ran into the same problem.

1. I inserted in my gemfilen gem 'rake', '~> 10.0.1' [in your case it should be '10.0.2']
2. I deleted my gemfile lock
3. I ran rake db:migration again and it worked.

I got this tip here: [Activated Ruby RAKE 10.0.1, require 10.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400587/activated-ruby-rake-10-0-1-require-10-0-0)

**Update:** In my case I didn't have rake duplicated. I just have in my gems the 10.0.1 version.

Answer (score 2):

Solved the same issue by running:

```
bundle update
```

This will update your rake gem to the latest version and allow you to run the migration.

If you are using a gemset: be sure to run `bundle install` after you've updated rake to update your local gemset as well.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you are using **rake** from the system. (latest version by default)
The solution is use follow command:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Also, you can create alias. Because this command is too big and difficult to write.

```
echo "alias be='bundle exec'" >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Then you can use follow short command:

```
be rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

change the version which located both in the gemfile and gemlock to the version number shown in the console, it will be done