# rake db:migrate RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, omniauth

well i try to install gem 'omniauth-twitter', create controllers and model this way

```
 rails g controller sessions
 rails g model userGem provider:string uid:string name:string
```

but, in the next step when i try to do a rake db:migrate, throw this error:

```
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 10.3.2, but your Gemfile requires rake         10.2.1. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.
/home/salinas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:34:in     `  block in setup'
/home/salinas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `  setup'
/home/salinas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `setup'
/home/salinas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `   <top (required)>'
/home/salinas/blog/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/salinas/blog/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/salinas/blog/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/home/salinas/blog/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/salinas/blog/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'    
/home/salinas/blog/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [rake aborted! You have already activated rake 10.0.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.2.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489953/rake-aborted-you-have-already-activated-rake-10-0-2-but-your-gemfile-requires)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Run the command as:-

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Or remove the `rake 10.3.2` as:-

```
gem uninstall rake
```

Select the `rake-10.3.2` to uninstall.

After removing `rake 10.3.2`, no need to append `bundle exec`.